# Do not display forms in JSF

Tags: maven, jsf

I started making a project (JSF+MAVEN) and immediately encountered some problems:
1)First one - my input textFields,buttons etc. do not displays on google page, something like on this picture. [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URphZ.png)
2)Second problem - "outputStylesheet" in home.xtml do not see my CSS folder and css file.[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibnDx.png)

I run this from home.xhtml->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
   <title>#{msg.index_title}</title>
   <h:outputStylesheet library="CSS" name="home.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>

   <div>
      <p> Please,enter your name</p>

      <h:form>
        <h:inputText  id="username" size="25" value="#{user.username}" 
        required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.login_required}" />
        <h:commandButton action="main?faces-redirect=true" value="Enter"/>
      </h:form>
  </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

This is my project structure->
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNaWn.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MySiteGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>MySiteMaven</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>MySiteMaven Maven Webapp</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
 <finalName>MySiteMaven</finalName>
<pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default- 
    bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
 </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>faces/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>nls.message</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>

</faces-config>
```

I will be very grateful to you for your help.

Comment: Try to find a modern tutorial. In you code you have a mixture of things from old and new jsf versions and your web.xml can be newer too version wise (and content can be resuced) docus on jsf 2.2 at least maybe even 2.3

Comment: I solved my first problem.I just replaced all my dependencies in pom.xml by  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
And everything works good.

Comment: why 2.2.7 when 2.2.14 is out???

Comment: Oh,i don't now about this.I'll will change it right now.Thanks for helping!

Comment: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html